# thin cloth phases through collision objects

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I have a vertex string with a cloth simulation but for some reason it just phases through collision objects

[image: phasing through the collision]

the high distance value on the cloth simulation is the only change i tried but it did nothing. apart from that the cloth is the default cloth simulation and the collision object is the default collision settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have faces to collide. You can make small faces and hide one side of faces using **mask** modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thx! As far as i know the hair simulator currently uses the same simulator as the cloth sim. Does hair work this way?

Comment: I don't know about hairs..